# Yajra Datatable relationship showing records in one column

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

Here's my ID column data structure

ID: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Here is my controller's code.

```php
$transaction = ExpenseEntry::with('transaction');

return DataTables::eloquent($transaction)
    ->editColumn('transaction', function (ExpenseEntry $expense) {
        return $expense->transaction->map(function ($transaction) {
            return $transaction->id;
        });
    })->make(true);
```

and Javascript Function

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#data-table').DataTable({
        "ordering": false,
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": '{!! route('
        expense_dts ') !!}',
        columns: [{
                data: 'id',
                name: 'id'
            },
            {
                data: 'expense_type',
                name: 'expense_type'
            },
            {
                data: 'amount',
                name: 'amount'
            },
            {
                data: 'date',
                name: 'date'
            },
            {
                data: 'description',
                name: 'description'
            },
            {
                data: 'transaction',
                name: 'transaction.id'
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

It is working but the problem is it is showing all the `transacation.id` in a table like this `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`

I want to get them like each id in each row with its column.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have to add make['transaction'] at the bottom of the addcoloumn code.as per use of yajra datatable.

Comment: How can you please share syntax with this code?

Comment: ->rawColumns(['transaction']) above of make your make true line of code just put this.

Comment: Still it shows the same could you please check the image and you will get the idea.

Comment: $transaction = ExpenseEntry::with('transaction')->get(); try this

Comment: Doesn't working

Comment: You can just print_r($transaction); first..

Comment: with dd it works, but on print_r gives error, ```Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65015808 bytes)
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198945/discussion-between-muhammad-javed-baloch-and-vikas).